# generate sqlalchemy filters dynamically from user input (in this case Jqgrid)

Tags: python, jqgrid, sqlalchemy

consider the following example.

```
{"groupOp":"AND","rules":[{"field":"Rate","op":"eq","data":"6"}],"groups":[{"groupOp":"OR","rules":[{"field":"Code","op":"eq","data":"abc"},{"field":"Name","op":"eq","data":"fd"}],"groups":[]}]}
```

1. Analyzing, I need to recursively generate binary expressions for each clause
2. Then combine the results using "and_" or "or_" functions.

However I am still stuck at point number one.

Any pointers on how to achieve it?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: I am still stuck with generating an filter for say '{"field":"Rate","op":"eq","data":"6"}'

Comment: i tried this BinaryExpression(Currencies.Code,'abc',operator.eq) but it gives error

Comment: another way might be eval... but that it would be better if i can avoid it

Comment: **How many rows you need to filter?** I invested before some time in **server side** filtering, but I use it now seldom because **client side** filtering is quickly enough. So back to the original question: How many rows you need to filter? And which page size you use currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming the meaning of "AND -> (rules), (groups)" means you want AND(rule1, rule2, rule3... group1, group2, group3...).  I'm not sure how else that would work.

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import *
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'thing'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Rate = Column(Integer)
    Code = Column(String)
    Name = Column(String)

rules = {
    "groupOp": "AND",
    "rules":[
        {
            "field":"Rate",
            "op":"eq",
            "data":"6"
        }
    ],
    "groups":[
        {"groupOp":"OR",
        "rules":[
            {"field":"Code", "op":"eq", "data":"abc"},
            {"field":"Name","op":"eq","data":"fd"}
        ],
        "groups":[]
    }
]}


from sqlalchemy import and_, or_
from operator import eq
lookup = {
    "AND": and_,
    "OR": or_,
    "eq": eq
}

def visit_rule(rules):
    fn = lookup[rules['groupOp']]
    return fn(
                *(
                    [visit_expr(expr) for expr in rules['rules']] +
                    [visit_rule(subrule) for subrule in rules['groups']]
                )
            )

def visit_expr(expr):
    return lookup[expr["op"]](
                getattr(Thing, expr["field"]),
                expr["data"]
            )

# thing."Rate" = :Rate_1 AND (thing."Code" = :Code_1 OR thing."Name" = :Name_1)
print visit_rule(rules)
```